# Calling object method within the object—error: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, methods, error-handling

I'm trying to call `getQuestions()` inside the same object it is a method of. But when I try to read the quizz.config.allQuestions property, I get an error message reading "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getQuestions' of undefined." Is there something I am missing here?

```
var quizz = {
    config: {
        urlJSON: 'questions.json',
        allQuestions: quizz.getQuestions()
    },

    getQuestions: function() {
        $.getJSON(quizz.config.urlJSON, function(questions) {
        return questions;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: The variable `quizz` is undefined until after the (whole) literal is evaluated. None of the properties exist (in a way that can be referenced) until after the whole object literal is evaluated, so during initialisation you can't set any properties equal to the result of the other properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're trying to assign to `allQuestions` the `quizz` object isn't done being initialized yet. So you'd have to do it after creating the object.

```
var quizz = {
    config: {
      urlJSON: 'questions.json'
      // don't declare allQuestions
    },
    getQuestions: ...
};
quizz.allQuestions = quizz.getQuestions();
```

The problem with **that** though is that `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function, meaning it won't return that value immediately. That's why it has a callback in it. Instead, you might try defining `getQuestions` like this:

```
getQuestions: function(callback) {
  $.getJSON(quizz.config.urlJSON, callback);
}
```

Then you can get the values like this:

```
quizz.getQuestions(function(questions) {
  quizz.config.allQuestions = questions;
});
```